# How to change an attribute of an array of objects correctly? Javascript ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have that array of objects:

```js
this.state = {
  itemSquare: [{
      item: "bomb",
      status: false
    }, {
      item: "bomb",
      status: false
    }, {
      item: "bomb",
      status: false
    },
    {
      item: "bomb",
      status: false
    },
    {
      item: "field",
      status: false
    },
    {
      item: "field",
      status: false
    },
    {
      item: "field",
      status: false
    },
    {
      item: "field",
      status: false
    },
    {
      item: "field",
      status: false
    },
    {
      item: "bomb",
      status: false
    }, {
      item: "bomb",
      status: false
    }, {
      item: "bomb",
      status: false
    },
    {
      item: "bomb",
      status: false
    },
    {
      item: "field",
      status: false
    },
    {
      item: "field",
      status: false
    },
    {
      item: "field",
      status: false
    },
    {
      item: "field",
      status: false
    },
    {
      item: "field",
      status: false
    }

  ],
}
```

And I want to change the `status` just from a given one, I'm doing so:

```js
teste = () => {
  this.state.itemSquare[0].status = true

  console.log(this.state.itemSquare)
}
```

However, I do not know why, it is altering others, what returns me is this:

```js
(18)[{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
0
  : {
    item: "field",
    status: true
  }
1
  : {
    item: "field",
    status: false
  }
2
  : {
    item: "field",
    status: false
  }
3
  : {
    item: "field",
    status: false
  }
4
  : {
    item: "bomb",
    status: false
  }
5
  : {
    item: "bomb",
    status: false
  }
6
  : {
    item: "field",
    status: false
  }
7
  : {
    item: "bomb",
    status: false
  }
8
  : {
    item: "field",
    status: false
  }
9
  : {
    item: "bomb",
    status: false
  }
10
  : {
    item: "field",
    status: false
  }
11
  : {
    item: "field",
    status: false
  }
12
  : {
    item: "bomb",
    status: false
  }
13
  : {
    item: "field",
    status: false
  }
14
  : {
    item: "bomb",
    status: false
  }
15
  : {
    item: "field",
    status: false
  }
16
  : {
    item: "field",
    status: true
  }
17
  : {
    item: "bomb",
    status: false
  }
length
  :
  18
__proto__
  :
  Array(0)
```

And as you can see the `16` was also changed, how? If I just asked for the 0 position.
Can someone help me?

Comment: You should use this.setState method in a immutable appeoach.

Answer (score 2):

Seems like these two objects are actually just one, referenced at two positions. So to resolve this, you have to clone / rewrite one of the objects so that it won't affect the other one:

```
this.state.itemSquare[0] = {
   item: "bomb"
   status: true
};
```

However rewriting the state in react is a very very bad thing. Instead you should call `setState` and mutate the state with a pure function:

```
this.setState(({ itemSquare }) => ({
  itemSquare: itemSquare.map(({ item, status }, index) => ({
    item, status: status || index === 0
  }))
}));
```

Answer (score 1):

May be your object at index 16 and 0 have same reference. Like in the example given below.

```js
var arr =[{"status" : false}];
arr[1] = arr[0];
console.log(arr[0]);
console.log(arr[1]);
arr[0].status = true;

console.log(arr[0]);
console.log(arr[1]);
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use `this.setState` method in a immutable approach.